# If a ball is the union of two sets, does one of them non empty interior?

Tags: general-topology, the-baire-space

Hi everyone: Suppose that an open ball $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$  $(m\geq2)$ can be written as the disjoint union of two sets: $B=E\cup F$. Can we conclude that one these sets,$E$ or $F$, has non empty interior? Thanks for you reply.

Comment: HINT: Consider $B\cap\Bbb Q^2$ and $B\setminus\Bbb Q^2$ when $m=2$. (This generalizes to larger $m$, and for that matter to $m=1$.)

Comment: You’re very welcome.

Comment: Another take on Brian's idea: Take $E=\{x \in B | \|x\| \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ and $F = B \setminus E$.

Comment: If the hints are enough for you, you can write a detailed proof and then accept it.

Comment: Note, that the question is equivalent to “is an open ball irresolvable?” Not only you can write a ball as a union of two disjoint dense subsets, you can write it as a disjoint union of continuum many dense subsets.

Comment: The answer is no. Let $B=(0,1)$, $E=B\cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $F=B\cap(\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q})$. Then $B$ is the union of $E$ and $F$, but none of these sets has interior points.